# Determine if current window is opened using fancybox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox

I have a page that can either be opened via Fancybox or viewed without fancybox. Can i somehow in javascript check if this page was opened using fancybox or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an external page, you would most likely open it with fancybox using `"type":"iframe"`

You could simply put this code inside that page:

```
if(parent.jQuery().fancybox) {
 alert("I was opened inside fancybox");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of a page views of a page that is viewed via fancy-box.

Let us say you have a "Terms and Conditions" page, and you have added a link to the page in footer navigation plus you have added a link on signup page.

```
<a href="#" id="terms-and-conditions-link" >Terms & Conditions</a>
```

As the above link opens "Terms & Conditions" in a popup, but people worry how to capture the views of the page that are viewed through fancy-box popup, well their is a very easy way to capture such page views, you can use Google analytic combined with jQuery.

Here the code

```
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

            // explicitly triggering a page view for Google Analytic 
            $('#terms-and-conditions-link').click(function(){
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/terms-accessed-via-fancybox']);
            });
```

The below code is doing the magic, you are explicity telling Google that a page on your site named "terms-accessed-via-fancybox" has been accessed, you can change "terms-accessed-via-fancybox" to any string you want.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/terms-accessed-via-fancybox']);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this if condition to test if I'm inside a fancybox:

```
//IE7-8 Fix: when not in iframe parent equals self
if (self != parent && typeof parent.$.fancybox !== 'undefined') {
    //Code to execute when inside the fancybox
}
```

This solution expects you to use an iframe to display the content of the page in the Fancybox and checks if the parent of the iframe has the fancybox plugin loaded.

*I am using the 1.3.4 version of the fancybox plugin.*

Comment: hi nebulousGirl, I have similar question i have a page that opens in fancy box as well as page so i want check if its inside a fancybox from code behind how can i do this ?